# How do you allow your program to read and Write in the Downloads Folder

Tags: android, file, kotlin, permissions

After scouring the Internet for information about granting Write permissions and getting backtracked by deprecated functions, I have found two terms, that should get me to get permissions to update files created in the Download Folder: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE from the Storage Acces Frame
and
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()

However, while the Storage Access Frame does not provide what i seek(people choose the save point, so whereever they choose I need permission to work), i can't get the requestPermissions() function to work.

So, How do you gain permission to change the files the app created somewhere(via Storage Acces Frame), possibly in a way that works in Android 9-11. Best would be in Kotlin, but at this point I'm not picky and will adapt whatever you can give me

Edit: Forgot to mention it, the File I use is a Textfile file with Json data

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with media files and targeting android q or more this could work:

given that you have gained file uri you want to  modify, you put accessing file code in try-catch block, and then you can catch RecoverableSecurityException from which you can get actionIntent and ask user to grant permission to modify particular file, Here is sample code for that

```
private fun onDeleteClick(uri: Uri?) {
    uri?.let {
        try {
            contentResolver.delete(it,null,null)
        } catch (se:SecurityException){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                val securityException = se as RecoverableSecurityException
                val intentSender = securityException.userAction.actionIntent
                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender.intentSender,0x11,null,0,0,0)
            } else
            {
                throw SecurityException()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To listen for user's response for permission request you override onRequestPermissionsResult like this

```
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode ==  1){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
            //you should be able to modify file now 
         
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission was denied to access files",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, that doesn't seem to be, what i'm searching for. I'm trying to write Json-data into a Textfile, which can later also be imported by the app, which results in "EACCES (Permission denied)" right now.